# Unable to prevent multiple button clicks with android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Currently I'm making a simple android app and I have one problem that I'm stuck for a while. I've read many articles over google on how to prevent multiple clicks with android , However, when I press the button there is no action taking place.
All I want to do is to prevent users from clicking more than one time. I've posted the sample code. I wonder if there are some errors ...

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;

public void sendData(View v) {

    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {

        return;
    }
    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    if ((number.getText().toString().equals("") || number.getText()
                .toString() == null)
                || (num.getText().toString().equals("") || num.getText()
                        .toString() == null)) {
        //alert the user
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insertnumber",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {

            return;
        }
        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        //sending the data
        trySendingData trying = new trySendingData();

        trying.execute();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to execute the asyncTask trying.execute(); with one click.

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons or single button?

Comment: Just disable your button on click and execute your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Only one single button, and I'm using the onClick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can call this method in onClickListener

```
 public static void blockView(final View v) {
    v.setEnabled(false);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            v.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

this will block the view for 1 second

Comment: All of you gave me a great help but your solution solved it all!

Answer (score 0):

Just say

```
Whateverbuttoncallssenddata.setEnabled(false);
```

or

```
Whateverbuttoncallssenddata.buttsetOnClickListener(null);
```

as long as it's not a textview.

Comment: I will try, but one thing that concerns me is , after the asyncTask is executed and goes to a different activity, then press the back button , will the buttons state still be false ?

Comment: I'm too sleepy to think that through but even if it does just setEnabled(true); in original page onCreate/Resume.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable button click once it is clicked by user `btnSendData.setEnabled(false)` , start executing the asynctask with task to be performed. Once task is finished either you can enable button click on asynctask's onPostExecute() method or you can get result back where you want and enable the button click again by calling `btnSendData.setEnabled(true)`

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to achieve this:

**Method 1:**

Set Tag.

Create the variable like

```
Boolean isClicked = false;
```

once your code reaches this

```
button.setonclick...{
if (!isClicked){
isClicked = true;
//Write your AsynkTask here
}
}
```

**Method 2:**

Disable button once clicked
ex.:

```
button.setonclick...{
    button.setEnabled(false);
    //Write your AsynkTask here
    }
    }
```

**Note :**
You are calling clcik action from xml so. You need to modify like this:
Under this method:

```
public void sendData(View v) {
v.setEnabled(false);
}
```

I think the second is you need. I add method 1 for information

Answer (score 0):

As Piyush and SmulianJulian said Disable click and if you make it enable then enable it in end of async task. Like this:

```
public void sendData(View v) {
//First disable button so user cannot click it immediately
  v.setEnable(false);

    if ((number.getText().toString().equals("") || number.getText() 
            .toString() == null) 
            || (num.getText().toString().equals("") || num.getText() 
                    .toString() == null)) { 
        //alert the user 
         Toast.makeText(this, "Insertnumber",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  v.setEnable(true);//This makes view clickable 

   } else { 

     //sending the data 
        trySendingData trying = new trySendingData()

{
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(View result) {
    //This makes view clickable after completing your asyncTask trySendingData
v.setEnable(true);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
    };
       trying.execute();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm getting closer to the solution, but the last thing I'm stuck with is that if I set the v.setEnabled(false) above the if condition I wont be able use the condition to check if the user had entered the number or not in the second time . How can I unset the setEnable(false) to true if the user had entered a number ?

Comment: Look at inside  `if` condition after Showing Toast message I have enabled view to clickable.